# Perl - Sorting Files having date value in filename

Tags: regex, perl, sorting, csv

I have a list of files in the directory for which I want to perform sort and get the latest file. I don't want to do it using latest modification time or created time. I want to sort based on the file name.

The File name will be in the format **DEV_TEST_DDMMYYYYHH24MISS.csv**

I need to write a perl script which will read the files from the directory and perform sorting based on the file name.

EX. File names:

```
DEV_TEST_24032015121022.csv 
DEV_TEST_04052015074942.csv 
DEV_TEST_12052015074942.csv 
DEV_TEST_05052015115948.csv
DEV_TEST_12022015115948.csv
```

The script should return `DEV_TEST_12052015074942.csv` as the latest file.

Can someone suggest a better approach?

It is enough if someone can provide sorting logic.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's easy to rearrange the dates so they can be sorted lexically.

Sort just by date-time:

```
my @sorted =
   map /\0(.*)/s,
   sort
   map {
      my ($d,$m,$y,$t) = /(\d{2})(\d{2})(\d{4})(\d{6})/;
      "$y$m$d$t\0$_"
   }
   @unsorted;
```

Sort by whatever comes before the date-time, then by date-time:

```
my @sorted =
   map /\0(.*)/s,
   sort
   map {
      ( my $fixed = $_ ) =~ s/(\d{2})(\d{2})(\d{4})(?=\d{6})/$3$2$1/;
      $fixed . "\0" . $_
   }
   @unsorted;
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use the [`Time::Piece`](https://metacpan.org/pod/Time::Piece) module to parse the digits in the file name in conjunction with `nsort_by` from [`List::UtilsBy`](https://metacpan.org/pod/List::UtilsBy) to order your file names

It would look like this

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use 5.010;

use Time::Piece;
use List::UtilsBy 'nsort_by';

my @names = <DATA>;
chomp @names;

my @sorted = nsort_by { Time::Piece->strptime(/(\d+)/, '%d%m%Y%H%M%S')->epoch } @names;

say for @sorted;

__DATA__
DEV_TEST_24032015121022.csv
DEV_TEST_04052015074942.csv
DEV_TEST_12052015074942.csv
DEV_TEST_05052015115948.csv
DEV_TEST_12022015115948.csv
```

**output**

```
DEV_TEST_12022015115948.csv
DEV_TEST_24032015121022.csv
DEV_TEST_04052015074942.csv
DEV_TEST_05052015115948.csv
DEV_TEST_12052015074942.csv
```

Comment: Hi Thanks for the reply. Unfortunately TIme::Piece module is not working .. Could you please suggest a way where we can extract the date part and then sort using or subroutine or something?

Comment: Time::Piece has been a standard part of a Perl installation since Perl 5.10.0 (in December 2007). If it's "not working" for you, it might be time to upgrade to a more up to date version.

Comment: Hi..Yes, the Time Piece Installation is not there. And the server which has those files is not under our control . We only have limited access.

Answer (score 0):

If your dates were in `YYYYMMDDHH24MISS` format, then a simple alphanumeric sort would suffice.  A substitution like the following on the filename will put them into this format:

```
$filename =~ s/(\d{2})(\d{2})(\d{4})(\d{6})/$3$2$1$4/;
```